# How to run OSSEC over TCP

Tags: ossec

I've got ossec working fine with several clients/agents with the default UDP:1514. However, after adding tcp to the server's ossec.conf file, removing and re-adding the agents, and restarting ossec on all machines, the agent logs show they are unable to contact the server, presumably because they are trying to do so over UDP.

While the [server doc](https://ossec-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/syntax/head_ossec_config.remote.html) for ossec.conf shows the protocol option where you can spec TCP or UDP, there is nothing like this in the [agent doc](https://ossec-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/syntax/head_ossec_config.client.html) for ossec.conf, so my question is how does one configure the agents to also use TCP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found by searching the ossec mailing list that this is not possible.